# Does integer value behave as string inside input text field?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to convert decimal value to hexadecimal value using `js`. I have two input text fields here. One for input value and other for output value. I have tried something like this first:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="input hexadecimal" id='mytxt' width="300" height="200">
<input type="button" value="click me" id='mybtn'>
<input type='text' id='here' >
<script>
function init(){
  var field=document.getElementById('mybtn');
  field.addEventListener('click',getvalue,false);
}
function getvalue(){
var input=document.getElementById('mytxt');

var x=input.value.toString(16).toUpperCase();
alert(x);
var here=document.getElementById('here');
here.value=x;

}

window.onload=init;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It was not working. I mean the integer value remains same on the output, like if I tried `15000`, it remains `15000`.

Then I changed my code a little.

I parsed the input value using parseInt, then applied `toString()` method to it. Now it works as I expected like for `15000` it gives me `0x3A98` in hexadecimal.

```
var y=parseInt(input.value);
var x=y.toString(16).toUpperCase();
```

***I have two questions regarding this post:***

**1.** Why integer values act as a string value inside text field. Is it by default?

**2.** I have tried `innerHTML` to show value in the output text field. It didn't work. Why `innerHTML` method didn't work with input text field?

Comment: 1) because input values are by default in `string`
2) because a input type have a value not `html` or a `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. It is by dedault. JavaScript `value` always return `string` so (as Tiago Reis wrote) it's good practise to parse it to the type we need.
2. `innerHTML` shows what's between opening and closing tag (e.g. `<div><p>test</p></div>` div's innerHTML is `<p>test</p>`). Value of `<input>` isn't inside of this tag and the tag itself is empty so using it will return empty string.

Answer (score 2):

The html input attrtibute value is a string type value.

So when used on javascript it's a best pratice to parse them to the type you want, like the parseInt to tell javascript this is a integer value.

can you show up the code of the innerHTML you are using?

Comment: instead of (here.value=x;) i tried (here.innerHTML=x;)

Comment: id="here" is an input field does not have an innerHtml property.... just value. Just has an value or other html attribute... Try your code on the browser console window.

Comment: what you are suggesting me to do.can you explain a little?

Comment: Whenerever you write javascript code, you can on chrome or firefox enable the developer tools, and the console window, there when you load up your page, if it has javascript errors it will catch them, if not, you can test you javascript code througt the console to check the results. You cannot had an innerHTML property to that input field, so to present your data you must use the value property.